# Web scraping tables from over 5K websites listed by url in a .csv file, all in R

Tags: css, r, rvest

So, I am working to extract data from the following website: http://livingwage.mit.edu
...at the county level, and have tried many different iterations of using the rvest package to extract the data. Unfortunately, there are about 5K counties.

I have extracted all the urls into a single column .csv file. The urls have the form "http://livingwage.mit.edu/counties/..." where "..." is the state code followed by the county code.

The data I want has the css identifier as (from SelectorGadget)

```
css = '.wages_table .even .col-NaN , .wages_table .results .col-NaN'
```

or the xpath of

```
xpath = //*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "wages_table", " " ))]//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "even", " " ))]//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "col-NaN", " " ))] | //*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "wages_table", " " ))]//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "results", " " ))]//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "col-NaN", " " ))]
```

This is where I started:

```
library(rvest)
url <- read_html("http://livingwage.mit.edu/counties/01001")
url %>%
html_nodes("table") %>%
  .[[1]] %>%
  html_table()
```

...but was only able to extract one table at a time, and got the headers and the final row, which I did not want.

So, I tried something like this:

```
counties <- 01001:54500
urls <- paste0("http://livingwage.mit.edu/counties/", counties)
get_table <- function(url) {
  url %>%
    read_html() %>%
    html_nodes("table") %>%
    .[[1]] %>%
    html_table()
}
results <- sapply(urls, get_table)
```

...but quickly realized that not all the numbers are sequential (they are mostly odd), but are not continuous either, i.e., one state may only have 4 counties, and only have urls that go up to ~/10009 for example.

Finally, I got as far as this when trying to access the .csv list of urls on my desktop:

```
URL <- read.csv("~/Desktop/LW_url.csv", header=T)
URL %>%
html_nodes("table", ".wages_table .even .col-NaN , .wages_table .results .col-NaN") %>%
  .[[1]] %>%
  html_table()
```

...and know that the css and the read all do not like talking to each other nicely.

Any help in making this happen would be thoroughly appreciated.

Comment: They obviously have this data in a "real" format somewhere (it's how they built the site). Have you tried e-mailing them (the e-mail link is on Dr Glasmeier's page) for it? Scraping will be prone to errors. It may take less than a day to get the actual data file.

Comment: If @hrbrmstr approach doesnt work you could try using `curl`(>2.0)'s async feature. Here is an example https://github.com/jeroenooms/curl/blob/master/examples/crawler.R and https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/curl/vignettes/intro.html#async_requests

Comment: @hrbrmstr and Floo0, thanks for the replies. I approached Dr. Glasmeier first and her response was, "At this point I don’t distribute data, though I am in the process of figuring out whether to do this or not." I could not convince her otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
install.packages("pbapply") # has a nice addition to lapply, estimates run time
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(pbapply)

## Get State urls

lwc.url <- "http://livingwage.mit.edu"

state.urls <- read_html(lwc.url)
state.urls %<>% html_nodes(".col-md-6 a") %>% xml_attr("href") %>% 
  paste0(lwc.url, .)



## get county urls and county names
    county.urls <- lapply(state.urls, function(x) read_html(x) %>% 
         html_nodes(".col-md-3 a") %>% xml_attr("href") %>% 
         paste0(lwc.url, .)) %>% unlist


## Get the tables Hourly wage & typical Expenses

dfs <- pblapply(county.urls, function(x){

  LWC <- read_html(x)

  df <- rbind(
    LWC %>% html_nodes("table") %>% .[[1]] %>%
      html_table() %>% setNames(c("Info", names(.)[-1])),

    LWC %>% html_nodes("table") %>% .[[2]] %>%
      html_table() %>% setNames(c("Info", names(.)[-1])))

  title <- LWC %>% html_nodes("h1") %>% html_text

  df$State <- trimws(gsub(".*,", "", title))
  df$County <- trimws(gsub(".*for (.*) County.*", "\\1", title))
  df$url <- x

  df

})

df <- data.table::rbindlist(dfs)
View(df)
```

Comment: This is a beautiful solution that has gathered more than what I needed, but I can definitely take it from here! I am entirely grateful for your willingness and ability.